# Mat ui FormControlLabel not using correct state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am using FormControlLabel for my custom checkboxes but they don't seem to be checked/unchecked based on the state being passed to them.

The onchange handler updates everything in redux/BE but on initial render or after reload they are all unchecked again.

I have tried so many methods that I have lost track and ended up in a bit of a spiral.

I have also tried controlling the checkbox using both value and checked.

when the checkboxes are rendered via the `.map` they have the correct `boolean` value being received from the state but the checkbox doesn't reflect that.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

I've put the file in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/SerdarMustafa1/052bffd6958858eb5770991f59d1e187

styled checkbox is :

```js
export const CustomCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: `${COLORS.MAIN_ORANGE}`,
    "&$checked": {
      color: `${COLORS.MAIN_ORANGE}`
    }
  },
  checked: {}
})(props => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
```

and the redux action/reducer:

```js
export const SET_IS_PIN_CODE_CHECK_IN_CHECKED =
  "venueTemplates/SET_IS_PIN_CODE_CHECK_IN_CHECKED";

export const setIsPinCodeCheckInChecked = createAction(
  SET_IS_PIN_CODE_CHECK_IN_CHECKED
);

export const handlers = {
  [SET_IS_PIN_CODE_CHECK_IN_CHECKED]: (state, { payload: value }) => ({
    ...state,
    isPinCodeCheckInChecked: value
  }),
```

Been going around in circles for ~10hrs, any ideas or help appreciated.

Comment: Please, add the code of how you use the component into the question itself, not only via the link to your source code.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, I did this because it was a lot of code. I will bear this in mind for next time.

Comment: You can still do that. It's not needed to add **all** the code, only the minimal relevant parts. If more parts are needed, people can ask for them in comments.

Comment: You can also add the different examples you tried and what was wrong with each.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but what worked for me was to use `defaultChecked`

example:

`defaultChecked={item?.isPinCodeCheckInChecked}`

Comment: This transforms the component to **uncontrolled**. If you do, you **must** ensure `defaultValue` remains unchanged during all component's lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `checked` (boolean) instead of `value` (string):

```js
                      <CustomCheckbox
                        id={id || ""}
                        onChange={event => handlePinCodeChecked(event)}
                        checked={!!isPinCodeCheckInChecked[id]}
                        name={name || ""}
                      />
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: You said `I have also tried controlling the checkbox using both value and checked`. I understood you used **both** (together). What I suggest here is **only use `checked`**.